# Get the default case for identifiers in JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While, in SQL, you can use double quotes to write identifiers in any case, DBMSes also have a "default" case that is used if the identifier isn't quoted. For example, PostgreSQL converts unquoted identifiers to lower case, while Snowflake converts them to upper case.

Does JDBC define a standard way of telling which it is for a particular DBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory the following methods from `DatabaseMetaData` should give you that information:

- `storesUpperCaseIdentifiers()`
- `storesUpperCaseQuotedIdentifiers()`
- `storesLowerCaseIdentifiers()`
- `storesLowerCaseQuotedIdentifiers()`
- `storesMixedCaseIdentifiers()`
- `storesMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers()`

But in my experience the information returned by the various drivers isn't 100% reliable.

The Postgres driver correctly reports `storesLowerCaseIdentifiers = true`.

The MySQL driver does not check the server's configuration e.g. the various combinations of the file system's behaviour, `lower_case_table_names` and `innodb_file_per_table`.

Comment: PostgreSQL actually does report the correct value, because `storesMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers()` is described as _"Retrieves whether this database treats mixed case quoted SQL identifiers as **case insensitive** and stores them in mixed case."_, and PostgreSQL does not handle quoted identifiers case-insensitively. You're thinking of `supportsMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers()` (_"Retrieves whether this database treats mixed case quoted SQL identifiers as **case sensitive** and as a result stores them in mixed case."_)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: ah, thanks. I removed that part

Comment: That said, the naming is not very clear and intention-revealing...